# SQL Group By with an Order By

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1111

I have a table of tags and want to get the highest count tags from the list.

Sample data looks like this

```
id (1) tag ('night')
id (2) tag ('awesome')
id (3) tag ('night')
```

using

```
SELECT COUNT(*), `Tag` from `images-tags`
GROUP BY `Tag`
```

gets me back the data I'm looking for perfectly. However, I would like to organize it, so that the highest tag counts are first, and limit it to only send me the first 20 or so.

I tried this...

```
SELECT COUNT(id), `Tag` from `images-tags`
GROUP BY `Tag`
ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

and I keep getting an "Invalid use of group function - ErrNr 1111"

What am I doing wrong?

I'm using MySQL 4.1.25-Debian

Answer (score 243, accepted):

In all versions of MySQL, simply alias the aggregate in the SELECT list, and order by the alias:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS theCount, `Tag` from `images-tags`
GROUP BY `Tag`
ORDER BY theCount DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: IMHO, this is the cleaner version than the selected answer. It's instantly clear what is ordered by. Of course, if its a quick script, that doesn't really matter.

Comment: Although OP is using MySQL, this answer also worked for me in HSQL (Libreoffice built-in)

Answer (score 55):

MySQL prior to version 5 did not allow aggregate functions in ORDER BY clauses.

You can get around this limit with the deprecated syntax:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), `Tag` from `images-tags`
GROUP BY `Tag`
ORDER BY 1 DESC
LIMIT 20
```

1, since it's the first column you want to group on.

Answer (score 13):

I don't know about MySQL, but in MS SQL, you can use the column index in the `order by` clause.  I've done this before when doing counts with `group by`s as it tends to be easier to work with.

So

```
SELECT COUNT(id), `Tag` from `images-tags`
GROUP BY `Tag`
ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Becomes

```
SELECT COUNT(id), `Tag` from `images-tags`
GROUP BY `Tag`
ORDER 1 DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 9):

In Oracle, something like this works nicely to separate your counting and ordering a little better.  I'm not sure if it will work in MySql 4.

```
select 'Tag', counts.cnt
from
  (
  select count(*) as cnt, 'Tag'
  from 'images-tags'
  group by 'tag'
  ) counts
order by counts.cnt desc
```

Comment: Seems to work for me in 10.1.14-MariaDB (MySQL-compatible).  I thought I had to have `) as counts`, but it still worked without the `as` part.

Answer (score -4):

Try this query

```
 SELECT  data_collector_id , count (data_collector_id ) as frequency 
    from rent_flats 
    where is_contact_person_landlord = 'True' 
    GROUP BY data_collector_id 
    ORDER BY count(data_collector_id) DESC
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question? The fields are not even the same.