# SQL query not sorting desc

Tags: sql, sqlite

This sql command works fine in sqlitemanager 
but in my android application this don't sort desc...

```
select t._id,  u.name, c.commdate, c.message
from tickets t, users u, comments c
where c.userid = u._id and c.ticketid = t._id
and t.status = 5
group by t._id
having max(c.commdate)
order by c.commdate desc
```

Comment: I prefer to use INNER JOIN when I want to get data depending on a few tables. Try with INNER JOIN to see if everything will be ok

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983/sql-group-by-with-an-order-by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a feeling the "having" part is a problem. Try (untested);

```
SELECT t._id, u.name, c.commdate, c.message
FROM tickets t
JOIN comments c ON (t._id = c.ticketid)
-- Find most decent comments on tickets, but handle lack of any comments
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c2.ticketid, MAX(c2.commdate) as max_commdate
    FROM comments c2
) AS latest ON (c.ticketid = latest.ticketid AND c.commdate = latest.max_commdate)
JOIN users u ON (c.userid = i._id)
WHERE t.status = 5
ORDER BY t._id DESC, c.commdate DESC
```

Comment: I/Database(15961): sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = no such column: latest.commdate

Comment: Whoops - SQL amended, try again.

Comment: the SQL worked bu still not ordered by commdate
it's ordered by ticket id :(((

Comment: It should be ordered by both - first by ticket id, and then by commdate. If you only want it ordered by commdate, just take out the first ORDER BY clause.

Comment: created a view with the previous query (without the order by) then query the view with mDb.query("solved", null, null, null, null, null, KEY_C_DATE + " DESC ");