# how to get ordered results in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a db named library. 
There are authors, books, books_genres, genres, history

I have more 5 books in genre with name "Horror", 3 books in genre with name "comedy" and 2 books in genre with name "Romance"

I have a check boxes with all my genres and when i selected them i want the results to be grouped by genre with most records on in on TOP.
Here is some code:

```
"SELECT title, price, genre_id, name
FROM books
INNER JOIN books_genres ON books.id = books_genres.book_id
INNER JOIN genres ON books_genres.genre_id = genres.id
WHERE genre_id IN ({$ids})";
```

this return to me all the books but without the order i want.

ids are string with genre ids like 1,2,3,4

Comment: see the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983/sql-group-by-with-an-order-by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [MYSQL's `ORDER BY`](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_order_by.asp) as in:

```
SELECT ... FROM .... WHERE ... ORDER BY id DESC
```

`DESC` is for descending order / `ASC` is for ascending order

**EDIT:** try this:

```
"SELECT title, price, genre_id, name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books_genres as b WHERE b.genre_id = genres.id) as genreCount
FROM books
INNER JOIN books_genres ON books.id = books_genres.book_id
INNER JOIN genres ON books_genres.genre_id = genres.id
WHERE genre_id IN ({$ids})
ORDER BY genreCount DESC, genres.id ASC;"
```

Comment: with this one i get results but not in wanted order

Comment: replace `id` with the name of the column you want to order by and `DESC` by `ASC` if you want the order to be ascending instead of descending. what is your wanted order?

Comment: i want the results to be grouped by genre with most records on in to be on TOP. So id or genre_id doesn't work well.

Comment: You'll have to change your query, one sec

Comment: Added query in answer. try it.

Comment: strange error this time: Unknown column 'genre_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: i don't have row named genre_id in books. genre_id is in books_genres
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM books as b WHERE b.genre_id = genres.id)

Comment: That explains alot.. edited. try again. next time try to be more clear.

Comment: I post all my tables above :) 
Everything works perfect now except "OREDER BY" :)
Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You use a subquery and the ORDER BY clause.

For example:

```
"SELECT title, price, genre_id, name, (SELECT count(*) FROM books AS bks WHERE bks.genre_id = books.genre_id) AS genre_count
FROM books
INNER JOIN books_genres ON books.id = books_genres.book_id
INNER JOIN genres ON books_genres.genre_id = genres.id
WHERE genre_id IN ({$ids})
ORDER BY genre_count DESC"
```

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'bks.genre_id' in 'where clause'