# Removing duplicates from SQL results

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble trying to retrieve data from mySQL table.  The table holds all the lap times from a racing event by all the participants.  The table has multiple entries for each race.  I would like to select each participant's best lap time, however I'm not sure how to get rid each participant's duplicates.

I've tried the following statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM   laptimes
GROUP  BY laptime,
          username
```

The table looks like this:

```
lap username    laptime
2   Blackvault  1200.000    
1   Blackvault  1234.000    
3   Elmo        1235.000
```

I'd like to display only lap 2 of Blackvault and Elmo's only lap.
The SQL will need to be generic as there could be N number of racers and N number laps.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: [SQL Group By with an Order By][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983/sql-group-by-with-an-order-by

This might be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the original data row (in MySQL), then you need to get the best time and connect it to the original data.  Here is a method using `join`:

```
select lt.*
from laptimes lt join
     (select username, min(laptime) as laptime
      from laptimes
      group by username
     ) lu
     on lu.username = lt.nusername and lu.laptime = lt.laptime;
```

If you don't need the `id` (or other columns), then the subquery might be sufficient for your purposes.

Comment: Best laptime means `min(laptime)`

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. That seems to return Blackvault's slowest time rather than his fastest.  Does an order by desc cause need to be added?

Comment: @Blackvault . . . No, `max()` just needs to be replaced with `min()`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to select only `best laptime` then you need this :

```
SELECT lap,username, min(laptime) as laptime
FROM laptimes 
GROUP BY username
```

Comment: i think you want to remove laptime from group by.

Comment: @Tim3880 : Ah yes, you right. Thanks for correction.