# What is the correct sequence of ORDER BY and GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I am beginner in mysql
Can anybody help me with the error on line number 5:

```
select a.*, count(b.user_id) as attempts from survey a 
left join survey_attempt b on a.survey_id = b.attempt_surveyid 
where a.survey_status != 0 
order by survey_order asc 
GROUP by a.survey_id
```

Comment: Switch group by and order by

Comment: specify table name in this line `order by a.survey_order asc`.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I was trying to have group by and order by, I got answer from below help, thanks guys

Answer (score 4):

Your ORDER BY should be after GROUP BY.

Answer (score 2):

Use `Group By` clause before `Order by` Clause.

As below :

```
select a.*, count(b.user_id) as attempts from survey a 
left join survey_attempt b on a.survey_id = b.attempt_surveyid 
where a.survey_status != 0 
GROUP by a.survey_id
order by survey_order asc
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allowed to `ORDER` before you `GROUP`, so your query should look like this:

```
select a.*, count(b.user_id) as attempts 
from survey a 
   left join survey_attempt b on a.survey_id = b.attempt_surveyid 
where a.survey_status != 0 
group by a.survey_id
order by survey_order asc
```

More details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27983/sql-group-by-with-an-order-by), where a similar question was asked and received more elaborated answers.

As a side note, try avoiding `*` and put required column instead.